# How can I stop my "Power and sleep buttons and lid settings" from automatically changing all values to "Do nothing"?

Tags: windows-11, power-management, bug

Today I opened "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings" and found out all of my setting were changed to "Do nothing". So I changed them as I had them before and saved changes. But after coming back to settings, everything was back at "Do nothing". Few weeks ago I noticed my power plan started automatically changing to "Default power plan", so I deleted it. When I check the settings back then, everything was fine. So I am not sure whether the problems could be related in some way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question perfectly. My own Windows 11 Pro laptops do not change these settings.

Most reasonable course of action in my experience with laptops is as follows:

Update UEFI BIOS (only manufacturer supplied BIOS update App).  Update all power drivers.  Restart, set Power Plan to Default.  Restart again and set as you wish.

When done Lid actions should work properly.

If not, and inasmuch as Windows 11 is not an issue, back up and reinstall Windows so as to get new drivers and new power settings.

Comment: Eeeeh! It is weird but I was able to change the option when I unplugged the laptop. Now it works (settings can be changed) also when the laptop is plugged in. I have no clue how this idea just struck but for whatever reason, it works. At least for now. (Shortly before this I specified button settings in group policy editor, that didn’t solve the problem, neither after restarting. But I think it might be good mentioning it.)

Comment: I would do the steps in my answer (nothing invasive - just updates) to ensure long term stability. I have had Windows 11 Pro running on 3 laptops always up to date for as long as 3 years with no issues here.

Comment: I think it might be good idea. As I am now getting “Your power plan information in not available.” for some reason.

Comment: That is in Control Panel, Power Options.

Comment: Yes. Aaah! F you Microsoft! As usual, solving one problem creates another.

Comment: Ok reseting (or well, deleting) my power plans with this command: “ powercfg -restoredefaultschemes” worked, eventually. I wonder for how long.

Comment: Do the updates I suggested. Power plans run for years with proper updating,

Comment: Anyway , reinstalling Windows or rolling back updates is also just temporary solution in my opinion.

Comment: My power driver are saying they are up to date and I don’t want to update BIOS-UEFI for this.

Comment: I think the problem has been solved until the Microsoft somehow “unsolves” the problem with another update. Yes, I believe the problem was caused by update, but I am not willing to roll back every time my PC automatically installs it.

Comment: Might be a videocard update. My AMD videocard installs AMD powerschemes. I can disable that. Not sure if Nvidia does something similar.